# how to click on the dropdown list items using selenium python without select tag?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I need to click on the dropdown list of items that are hidden and only the list visible once we click on the particular search box.

HTML TAG:

```
<div class="main-search_suggestions suggestions-list-container search-suggestions-list-container hidden" data-component-bound="true">
   <ul class="suggestions-list" role="listbox" aria-label="Search results">
       <li class="item suggestion suggestions-list-item " role="option" tabindex="0" aria-label="category" data-suggestion-type="category" data-param-type="find_desc" data-suggest-query="Restaurants" data-ajax-data="null">
       <li class="item suggestion suggestions-list-item " role="option" tabindex="0" aria-label="category" data-suggestion-type="category" data-param-type="find_desc" data-suggest-query="Universities" data-ajax-data="null">
       <li class="item suggestion suggestions-list-item " role="option" tabindex="0" aria-label="category" data-suggestion-type="category" data-param-type="find_desc" data-suggest-query="Hospitals" data-ajax-data="null">
       <li class="item suggestion suggestions-list-item " role="option" tabindex="0" aria-label="category" data-suggestion-type="category" data-param-type="find_desc" data-suggest-query="Hotels" data-ajax-data="null">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

from the above Html how to click those lists of items with either XPath/tag_name/class_name in python selenium based on the index value ?.

EDIT: (My code)

```
   def vendor_list():
    zipcode = (str(input("enter the zipcode:")))
    driver = open_driver_connection()
    print("Openning")
    driver.get('URL OF MY WEB PAGE')
    zipcode_value = driver.find_element_by_id('dropperText_Mast')
    zipcode_value.clear()
    zipcode_value.send_keys(zipcode)
    service_box = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"find_desc"))).click()
    drop_down = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='header_find_form']/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li") 
    for lists in drop_down: 
        lists.click()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you click on the search box first, as a normal user would have to do?

Comment: yes, once after clicking the search box the hidden dropdown will be listed. as a normal user, we should select accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"xpath of drop down"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "xpath of drop down list")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "xpath of drop option"))).click()
```

Click on the dropdown , wait for the visibility of list , and then click on the option from the list

Comment: Got an error:  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'

Comment: updated missed intializing webdriver wait

Comment: thanks @steve. incase if i need to select the list one after the another and run as per my requirement how should i need to do it ?

Comment: @Ammu you have to repeat the 3 step , again in loop

Comment: could you accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: can u also say how to loop this

Comment: create for loop with a list contianing xpath of options you want to click , and add the three waits in it

Comment: sry for more questions. i have a doubt, how the user will select their required item in the search box from the drop down

Comment: use the xpath //*[contains(text(),"somethig")]

Comment: am i doing it right?...i am beginner to this..thats y i am stucking here